# Filter on a dynamodb statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Its a small query I just want to get those records which have event name = 'newevent'

how to apply this filter as in documentaion all queries are of composite keys like this

```
face = dynamodb.get_item(
                                TableName='athlete_collection',
                                Key={'RekognitionId': {'S': match['Face']['FaceId']}
                                    ,'EventName': {'S' : 'celeb'}
                                     }
                            )
```

but in my case its not composite key .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dynamodb scan API with *FilterExpression*. 
See the examples below:

*AWSCLI:*

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name sample --filter-expression "eventname = :val" --expression-attribute-values '{":val":{"S":"newevent"}}' --region us-west-1
```

Output:

```
{
    "Count": 1,
    "Items": [
        {
            "eventname": {
                "S": "myname"
            },
            "id": {
                "N": "4"
            },
            "value": {
                "S": "value4"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ScannedCount": 5,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

Boto3 SDK:

```
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-1')

response = client.scan(
    TableName="sample",
    FilterExpression="eventname = :val",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ":val":{
            "S":"myname"
        }
    }
)
print(json.dumps(response, indent=True))
```

All the examples provided above will return all the attribues. If you need only specific attribute, use ***--projection-expression*** (In awscli) or ***ProjectionExpression*** (In SDK).

I recommend you to go through the below document links for more clarity and customizations:

[DynamoDB Scan API document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html)

[Working with DynamoDB Queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html)

Comment: in get_item I cant filter result ?

Comment: There is no filter for get_item. You use get item when you want to retrieve records which based on primary key/composite keys. You have mentioned that in your case *eventname* is not a key.

Comment: yes Eventname is not a key . So How can I make it composite key ? will this work for me ?

Comment: And who to get result according to this key in scan ?  Key={'RekognitionId': {'S': match['Face']['FaceId']}

Comment: *scan* API is used if you dont want the key conditions to be included. If you want to include the existing keys as well, you can do so using the *query* API. Set the *KeyConditions*, *KeyConditionExpression* and the *QueryFilter* parameters of the API similarly as shown in the above example.